# Table Per Type(TPT) hierarchy vs Navigation in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have been reading about Entity Framework during the pass few weeks. I came across TPT subject. I am a little bit confused and have difficulty to differentiate between TPT and Navigation. When should we choose one over another. Please take a look at the code below.

**A. Navication**

```
 public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public List<ContractEmployee> ContractEmployees { get; set; }
    public List<PermanentEmployee> PermanentEmployees { get; set; }

}

public class ContractEmployee 
{
    public int HourlyWorked { get; set; }
    public int HourlyPay { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

}

public class PermanentEmployee 
{
    public int AnnualSalary { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

**B. TPT**

```
[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

}

[Table("ContractEmployee")]
public class ContractEmployee : Employee
{
    public int HourlyWorked { get; set; }
    public int HourlyPay { get; set; }

}

[Table("ContractEmployee")]
public class PermanentEmployee : Employee
{
    public int AnnualSalary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: For this exact scenario I wouldn't use either of the approaches, they're both pretty bad (one-to-many in your "Navigation" scenario) and an extra table for few fields in your "TPT" scenario. You could preferably have the fields in the main Employee object with an enum switch between the rate of pay fields.

Comment: Honestly I'd suggest reading about data normalisation before moving forward. You don't need an inheritance pattern right now, though.